# Rectangle Button - Change the 'Grey colour' after tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface

Ok so I use the iPhone SDK

On IB I used a rectangle button, once you press that button and hold, it goes a gray colour - I want to change that gray color to an image I made.

So once the user touches the button, it goes to the image which I made.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for using 'to tap' instead of 'to click'.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you'll need to change the button's type to "custom" and provide images for each control state that you need. In this case, it sounds like you'll need to set an image for "default" state and "highlighted" state.

Comment: I tried changed it the image to custom on highlighted, but still the button goes  grey